# What is default and why is not overridable?

Tags: c#

While performing code review, I found code that could cut down on potential bugs by using the Null object pattern. Then I began thinking: wouldn't it be useful if the default value of that business object was a null object instead of a null reference?

Since C# provides the default operator, I tried to overload it like this:

```
public static MyObject operator default (MyObject object) 
{
    return MyObject.Null;
}
```

That gives me the error: 'Overloadable unary operator expected'. On further digging, I found that one part of the docs says that default(T) is a Primary operator:[Overloadable Operators](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8edha89s%28v=VS.71%29.aspx).

And when you actually click on default(T) on the above page, it says default is a keyword.

On top of that, this page doesn't say that default is not overloadable: [Overloadable Operators (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8edha89s%28v=VS.100%29.aspx).

I know this is kind of academic but I am trying to understand the language deeper. What is default(T)? Is it an operator or a keyword? And why is not overloadable (from a language design standpoint)?

UPDATE: Yes I've read C# language spec section 7.5.13 and I know what the language does. I am trying to understand why.

Comment: What in the world are you talking about?   "null object pattern"?   "null object instead of a null reference"!?  Overloading a reserved *keyword*?

Comment: `default(T)` for reference types returns null while for value types (like `int`) returns their default value (0 in case of `int`, `false` in case of `bool`, etc)

Comment: @Kirk Woll: The "null object pattern" is a design pattern in which an "empty" (or "null" if you will) singleton instance is created and used whenever null might otherwise be returned by the class. The idea is that you can check for the null object rather than null itself, yet if you try to use the null object, you won't get a `NullReferenceException` because you CAN invoke methods on a null object (it's an object, just one that "works like" null and does nothing meaningful). I don't use it myself, nor do I like it, but that's how the terminology is differentiated in this question.

Comment: @Kirk the Null Object pattern is quite common and I use it all the time - see for example http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?NullObject . The idea is to have an actual object so that you can have the methods raise a custom exception, or perform some other error-handling behaviour, rather than raise an exception and have to catch it all over the system (or check references for null-ness).

Comment: @Platinum, thanks, your explanation was helpful.

Comment: @Karl, seems to me it's a recipe for bugs.  Isn't it better to fail fast/early than to hide potential bugs?  An NRE is always the result of a **bug** and shouldn't be swept under the carpet.

Comment: A trivial (and not always practical) example of the Null Object pattern: in code that uses Strings, never return or expect null, but instead use `""`. Now code that checks the `.length` of a result doesn't need to be exception-checked, and results of 0 can be handled specially if needed.

Comment: @Kirk When used properly, it does not hide the bugs; it gets rid of them by simplifying the code. See the link for more explanation. For example, a "null" tree node participating in a tree size calculation can return 0, while the normal behaviour is to return 1 + size of left child + size of right child. Now there is no need to check whether the children are actually present.

Comment: @Kirk: The point of the null object pattern isn't to hide bugs; rather, it is to turn bugs from obscure, hard-to-debug "null reference exception" bugs into meaningful, more easily diagnosed bugs. When you deref a null, you don't know whether it was a string or a nullable int or a delegate or what. Suppose for example you use the null object pattern to represent the non-existent child of a tree's leaf node. Where before a bug would generate a null ref exception, now you can generate a "you're trying to get the value out of an invalid tree node" exception. That's way more information.

Comment: @Eric, @Karl, thanks for taking the time to explain.  Appreciate it!

Comment: And then there are the cases where you don't actually need an exception. A simple example is when using DI to add a logger to a class; if you don't actually want to log anything, and you represent this by injecting `null`, you have to check for `null` all over the place where you make the `.log()` calls. If you have a "logger" that doesn't actually do anything when you call `.log()`, then you can use it transparently.

Comment: Another example: say you DI a list of callbacks for an event. What should you store if you don't want to respond to the event? If you said `null`, you are going to end up writing more complex code, albeit perhaps saving a few bytes. If you said "an empty container", then you are using the null object pattern without having really realized it. :)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Overloading `default` would complicate the design of C# and the runtime significantly. Currently it is assumed that the binary zeroing of any value type is valid and equivalent to `default` of that value type. And for references the `null` reference is always valid and equivalent to `default` of any reference type.

This allows the runtime to start running the constructors on an objects in a binary zero state and get sane behavior.

Comment: I didn't understand the link between the two: what does that assumption have to do with being able to run constructors on objects? What is "sane" behavior? And doesn't default(T) come into play only when it's called explicitly in code?

Comment: Eric's explanation helped me see this link.

Comment: Empty fields get effectively initialized to `default(T)`. The role of `default(T)` is giving you access to a low level feature which gives you a valid value for any type without invoking any user code. It's most common use is in generics, where overloading obviously doesn't work.

Answer (score 20):

[@codesinchaos' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6472818/2361131) is basically spot on. A few additional thoughts.

Suppose you made an array of a thousand of your objects. Should every element of the newly-allocated array be initialized to your default value? Should the operator be invoked a thousand times?

What if the operator returns different values at different times?

What if the operator throws an exception?

In that scenario can a partially-initialized object be observed to be in a "pre-default-value" state?

Suppose MyObject.Null is a field. What is the value of the field *before* the `default` operator runs? Is that observable? Can you go into an infinite loop, trying to set MyObject.Null to its default value, which is MyObject.Null?

And so on. These are the sorts of questions language designers have to deal with when considering features like this. Most of the time, the solution is to not do the feature rather than try to figure out answers to all these tricky problems.

Thanks for pointing out that the documentation is deficient; I'll mention it to the documentation manager.

To answer your additional questions:

`default` is a reserved keyword of the C# language and has been since C# 1.0.  The following are its usages in C#:

1. The `default` operator is an operator whose argument must be the name of a type, like the `typeof` operator or the `sizeof` operator. This feature was added in C# 2.0 because it is handy when you have generics in the type system.  Reference: *[default operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/default#default-operator)*.
2. The `default` literal: beginning with C# 7.1, you can use the `default` literal to produce the default value of a type when the compiler can infer the expression type. Reference: *[default literal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/default#default-literal)*.
3. `default` can also be used to mark the default case of a `switch` statement.
4. `default` can be used as part of a "preprocessor" directive.

Comment: Answer #1337.  Very c00l man.  I enjoy reading your answers Eric.

Comment: I love Eric's sense of humor. Repped :O

Comment: How can it be used as part of a preprocessor directive?

Comment: Loved the reasoning: `This feature was added in C# 2.0 because it is handy when you have generics in the type system.` (detailed also at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6472794/what-is-default-and-why-is-not-overridable/6472925#comment7606188_6472818)

Answer (score 2):

> Then I began thinking: wouldn't it be
>   useful if the default value of that
>   business object was a null object
>   instead of a null reference?

It sounds like your project would benefit from using an IOC container that could inject a `NullBusinessObject` instance by default that does whatever you want it to do as default behavior. C# itself doesn't offer anything built in that you could override in this regard.

Comment: I am in the process of upgrading our framework to use Ninject but hadn't thought of this. Great suggestion, thanks!

Comment: @Space Cow: Logging is a typical example where you can use a `NullLogger` which just does nothing (i.e when using the class in a unit test), IOC makes this very easy to setup.

Answer (score 1):

`default(T)` usually "zeros-out" creates a null reference for classes, and a zeroed out version of value types (struct in C#).  `default` is a keyword in C# and an operator in MSIL.  C# does not allow overriding of default.