# Non-null class default in C#

Tags: c#, class, struct, default-value

If I `default(RefType)` I get `null`. If I `default(ValType)` I get a `ValType` with `default`-ed properties. That's fine.

But I want a ref-type with val-type `default` semantics; particularly for subtypes. Is this possible?

Say, I expose an interface, `IExtension`. 
Someone implements it as a class as `FooExtension`
How can I most easily get "`default`" instances of `FooExtension` as an "empty" class (and, equally importantly, types derived of `FooExtension`) without having to change the implementation?

This is important to me; I need to create non-`null`, "empty" instances of the derived types, so that they can be populated by a dynamic UI.

I'm guessing the answer will be something to the effect of iterating properties via reflection, but perhaps there's a better (read: cleaner) way.

I would just use structs, but the non-inheritable constraint, paired with the semantics of the types I'm describing being wrong, makes me wary (read: nope)

tl;dr: how do I get default classes like default structs, with inheritance supported implicitly.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is default and why is not overridable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6472794/what-is-default-and-why-is-not-overridable)

Comment: The `default` keyword always returns null for reference types so that's off the table. Perhaps you could use `Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(FooExtension))` to create these empty instances and require that the implementer always provide a constructor with no parameters.

Comment: *"Is this possible?"* Nope! Pass a function to create default instances, as in `UseAnExtension<FooExtension>(() => new FooExtension())`.

Comment: @mikez But I can't force a nonarity constructor in C#. I'd prefer to make this foolproof.

Comment: Sure you can't really force it at compile time, but requiring a constructor with no formal parameters is pretty standard. Another option is to give callers a static method to register a factory method that can create instances. But then of course they need to know how and when to call said factory method.

Comment: This feels like an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) you want to know how to do something, but you don't describe why, so no one can suggest a possible different approach.

Comment: @juharr Not really, the situation I described was exactly it: I expose an interface and want to be able to create instances of anything that implements it, where the instances are non-null with defaults for their properties (preferably with its properties observing the default semantics I've just described too) All of this is for an ad-hoc extension architecture which I can't drastically change.

Comment: So far as I can tell, I'm gonna need to write an `Empty<T>` extension method on `Type`, or something to that effect, that uses reflection voodoo to accomplish this.

Comment: I mean if you want some voodoo, there's [`FormatterServices.GetUninitializedObject`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.formatterservices.getuninitializedobject(v=vs.110).aspx) which creates an instance without calling any constructors. Generally, that is deeply confusing unless you eventually call one of the types constructors.

Comment: @mike Now *that sounds like the voodoo I want*! I'm on my phone so I'll have a look when I get back to my desk shortly.

Comment: @juharr Okay I'll try again: I want to receive, on the front end, "empty" objects of any type that are derived of type X which I specify, so my UI can populate them and send them back for processing. Because extensibility.

Comment: @mikez Upon closer inspection, that does seem like the voodoo I'm after. It won't initialize properties likewise, but nonetheless. Please make that an answer and I'll accept (after waiting a bit for more potential voodoo)

Comment: Particularly, "The current method should only be used for deserialization when the user intends to immediately populate all fields." -- fits the premise quite clearly.

Comment: @juharr Having recently commented as I did, perhaps this is a better description of the problem: how can I serialize an empty object by type, rather than by instance?

Comment: I feel that you could narrow down the questions significantly rather than try to find a solution to a generic problem.

Comment: Note that using `GetUninitializedObject` is quite dangerous, especially on types you don't own (like in your case when "someone implements" target type). They might initialize some readonly variable in constructor for example - and you will never run constructor so will face exceptions when trying to access some properties, and so it goes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is [`FormatterServices.GetUninitializedObject`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.formatterservices.getuninitializedobject(v=vs.110).aspx) which allocates an instance without calling any constructors. Generally, that is deeply confusing unless you eventually call one of the types constructors or initialize the object fully. As the name suggests, it is intended for creation of objects from serialized data but which might not have 0-arity constructors.

Comment: Thank you @mikez, is there an example for cases where you'd want to use this recursively? As to instantiate a whole object graph for subsequent population?

Comment: @Dan I suppose you could do that but it would take some analysis of the specifics. How do you know some property on a sub-object is set? How will collection types (arrays, lists, dictionaries) be handled?